# Can you use html attributes to a lightning:button?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In html you can add html attributes like

```
<button data-myattribute="hello world" />
```

If I am using lightning:button, how do i do this?

```
<lightning:button data-myattribute="hello world" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In Aura, you can't add data attributes to components. The usual solution is to put the data up on the nearest HTML element.

```
<span data-myattribute="hello world">
  <lightning:button onclick="{!c.sayGreeting}" label="Greet Me!" />
</span>
```

---

```
sayGreeting: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert(event.target.closest('[data-myattribute]').dataset.myattribute);
}
```

Or, depending on your use case (e.g. inside an `aura:iteration`) you might want to place the data even higher up the DOM so all of your elements can access it. The `closest()` method finds the nearest match based on a CSS selector (here, the nearest parent element that has the data-myattribute attribute).